# MongoDB integration with Solr

Tags: mongodb, solr

I am beginner with mongodb and its integraiton with Solr. From different posts I got an idea about the integration steps. But need info on the below

1. I have the data in mongodb, for faster retrieval we are integrating it with Solr. 
   Solr indexes all mongodb entries. Is this indexing one time activity after integration or Do we need to periodically update Solr to index the entries which got inserted after the integration ?
2. If we need to periodically update solr, it becomes an extra overhead to maintain it in Solr as well along with mongodb. Best approaches on overcoming it.

Answer (score 10):

As far as I know you do not have official(supported/complete) solution to integrate MongoDB and Solr, but let me give you some ideas/direction.

1. For me the best approach is when it is possible to modify the application and add to the persistence layer the fact that you have all writes operations done in MongoDB and Solr in the "same" time. Like that you can control exactly what you want to send to the Database and what you want to index for a full text operation. But as I said this means that you have to change your application code. (You will have anyway to change it to be able to query Solr when needed). And yes you have to index all the existing documents the first time
2. You can use a "connector" approach where MongoDB and Solr are kind of connected together, this could be done in various ways.

   You can use for example the MongoDB Connector available here : https://github.com/10gen-labs/mongo-connector

   LucidWorks, the company behind Solr has also a connector for MongoDB, documented here : http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/help/Create+a+New+MongoDB+Data+Source# (I have not used it so cannot comment, but it is also an approach)

You point #2 is true, you have to manage two clusters and be sure the data are in sync, and sometimes pay the price of inconsistency between the Solr index and the document just updated in MongoDB... So you need to see if the best approach for your application is to use MongoDB alone or MongoDB with Solr (see comment below)

Just a small comment in addition to this answer:
*You are talking about "faster retrieval", not sure it should be the reason, if you write correct queries with correct indexes in MongoDB you should be able to do it without Solr. If you requirement is really oriented towards the power of solr meaning: full text index (with all related features it makes sense)*

Comment: Thank Tug Grall for the detailed response.
We also have text search capability build in mongo and it has nice indexing feature, from the faster retrieval perspective, would it be close to retrieval performance of that of Solr ? 
Even if it is close, we are fine with it. Basically we are trying a small POC on mongodb indexing VS Solr search results.

Comment: Yes it should be, but as you can guess it depends a lot of the dataset itself, the type of query... the best is really to test. (should be easy since you have your data already and know which query you want) - just to be sure let me point you to the documentation : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/

Answer (score 1):

How large is your data? MongoDB has a few good indexing mechanism of its own.

There is a powerful geo-api and for full text search there is http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/. So it would be ideal to identify if your need fits into MongoDB or you need to spill over to SOLR.

About the indexing part. How often if your data updated? If you can afford to have infrequent updates, then a batch job with once a day re-indexing may work for you. Ideally SOLR would work well for some form of master data.

Comment: 1.Data is pretty huge in TBs distributed across multiple shards.
2.Data update is in two ways 
  a: Online 
  b: In Batch

Comment: It might be useful to try the Mongo connector from lucidworks as suggested by Tug Grall. It looks like it pulls out data using oplog, so it might be near-real-time. This might come close to what you want - and might be worth a look. The best thing, ofcourse, would be if you could use Mongo 2.6+ and use the text search API. Good Luck!